# PEP style guide for from module import with very nested module structure

Tags: python, python-3.x, pep8, pep

Suppose I need the function `foo` and that `foo` just so happens to be defined under `library.lgmodule.medmodule.smmodule.nichemodule.utils.something.else`

Is there a cleaner way to write:

```
from library.lgmodule.medmodule.smmodule.nichemodule.utils.something.else import foo
```

e.g. akin to the multi-line `import`:

```
from module.utiles import (foo, bar, baz, ban, ana,
    some, more, funcs, etc)
```

Comment: I think that this problem is telling you that you need a cleaner architecture for your modules. The nesting looks too deep for me. Answering only to what you asked, I think you have always to mention the path somewhere, even if you hide it behind an imported alias name.

Comment: @progmatico could be, but alas I did not design the library. Anyway it isn't too big of a deal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `importlib.import_module` and use some kind of string formatting.
For example:

```
from importlib import import_module

path = '.'join[
    'library',
    'lgmodule',
    'medmodule',
    'smmodule',
    'nichemodule',
    'utils',
    'something',
    'else'
]
foo = import_module('{}.foo'.format(path)
```

Comment: This is an *alternative* way to import the module, but that does not look *cleaner* to me.